# Website not being served (NGINX, Ubuntu)

Tags: nginx, website

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
    # multi_accept on;
}


http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/matsci.io/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name matsci.io www.matsci.io;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }

}
```

I have custom name servers active in my DNS settings of google domains and have networking records set up.(see image link)

[image: 1]

I have an example html file (`index.html`) that says "Title" when compiled in `/var/www/example.com/html/index.html`.

I set up my firewall ssh, etc. using this guide : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You domain currently does not have any A/AAAA records configured.

Following the details in the [Digital Ocean DNS tutorial](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/dns/how-to/manage-records/),  you will need to create A/AAAA records for your domain with hostname `@` and with hostname `www`.